# matlab solving numerical differential equations [pic]

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, nonlinear-equation, optics-algorithm

I'm trying to solve this numerical differential equations, can someone help?
[image: pic of the differential equations]

```
clc;
clear;
syms A1(z) A2(z)
lamda1 = 1560*(10^-9);
c=3*(10^8);
d_eff=27*(10^-12);
omga1=(2*pi*c)/(lamda1);
omga2=omga1*2;
n=2.2;
k1=(n*omga1)/c;
k2=(n*omga2)/c;
ode1 = diff(A1) == (2*i*(omga1^2)*d_eff*A2*conj(A1)*exp(-i*(2*k1-k2)*z))/(k1*(c^2));
ode2 = diff(A2) == (i*(omga2^2)*d_eff.*(A1.^2).*exp(i*(2*k1-k2)*z))/(k2*(c^2));
odes = [ode1; ode2];
cond1 = A1(0) == 1;
cond2 = A2(0) == 0;
conds = [cond1; cond2];
M = matlabFunction(odes)
sol = ode45(M(1),[0 20],[2 0]);
```

Comment: If you want a numerical solution, why do you employ the symbolic features of matlab?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Two non-linear, coupled ODEs.  Try a Runge-Kutta integration.

Answer (score 0):

in this question both **ODE** are coupled, hence there's only 1 **ODE** to solve:

**1.-** use 1st equation to write

```
A1=f(A2,dA2/dz)
```

and feed this expression into 2nd equation.

**2.-** regroup

```
n1=1j*k1^4/k2^2*1/deff*.25

n2=1j*3*(k1-k2)
```

now the **ODE** to solve is

```
y'=n1/y^2*exp(n2*z)
```

**3.-** It can obviously be done in MATLAB, but for this particular **ODE** in my opinion the **Wolfram online ODE Symbolic Solver** does a better job.

Input the obtained **ODE** of previous point into the **ODE** solver available in this link

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27+%2B+y+%3D+0

and solve

**4.-** The general (symbolic) solutions for `A2` are

[image]

Note that I used `k1` instead of `n1` and `k2` instead of `n2` just in the Wolfram **ODE** Solver.

Rewording ; the `k1` `k2` expressions of the general solutions are not the wave numbers `k1` `k2` of the equations in the question. Just replace accordingly.

**5.-** Now get `A1` using expression in point 2.

**6.-** I have spotted 2 possible errors in the MATLAB code posted in the question that shouldn't be ignored by the question originator:

In the far right side of the posted MATLAB code, the exponential expressions

**6.1.-** both show

*exp(-i*(2*k1-k2)*z))/(k1*(c^2))

there's this `(k1*(c^2))` dividing the exponent wheras in the question none of the  exponentials show such denominator their respective exponents.

**6.2.-** the `dk` or `delta k` expression in the exponentials of the question are obviously `k2-k1` or `k1-k2` , here there may be room for a sign ambiguity, that may shoot a wave solution onto the opposite direction, yet the point here is where

```
*exp(-1i*(2*k1-k2)*z)
```

should probably be

```
*exp(-1i*2*(k1-k2)*z)
```

or just

```
exp(-1i*(k1-k2)*z)
```

**6.3.-** and yes, in MATLAB `(-1)^.5` can be either expressed with `1j` or `1i` but as written in the MATLAB code made available in the question, since only a chunk of code has been made available, it's fair to assume that no such `i=1j` has been done.

Comment: to solve numerically with MATLAB first you have to define the group of points where you want to solve the ODE. These points are commonly referred as : 'frame' or 'mesh' or  'cavity' or 'waveguide' . This is, the space where you intend to solve the propagation or otherwise attenuation of these, let me call A1 A2, waves.

Comment: The first equation cannot be written as `A1=f(A2,dA2/dz)` !? But the second can as `A1=f(dA2/dz).`

Comment: Yves, the equations are differential because operators d()/dz are used, and the soulght solutions are also functions on t : A1(z,t)  A2(z,t). Then, differential equations can (or cannot) be solved symbolically or numerically.

Comment: When solving symbolically one chooses primitives that may work, along with parameters that can be left open, without really defining them, and this is why differential equations solved symbolically often have groups of families of functions are solutions, not just one A1 and one A2 as solution, but A1(z,t,C1,C2, ..) A2(z,t,C1,C2, ..) as solutions

Comment: However the numerical approach to solve DE is often chosen because the solutions are reached by approximations and then more often than one one gets to just a pair of A1 A2 as I assume is what you are asking for.

Comment: So, to solve DE numerically (not symbolically) one has to define a domain where to start with, including initial conditions, and then start approximating. What is the z domain you intend to solve and find A1 A2 for? [0 1] ? [0 Inf] ?

Comment: Why do you tell me that ? Better fix your post.